# Displaying Dicom File as a List of Image Sequence in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, dicom

I need to display a list of dicom file as image sequence in html and I wonder if it's possible to do so. If it is, how can I achieve the effect? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There are a few open source viewers that will help you do this. You can check:

1. OHIF viewer

   - GitHub Link: https://github.com/OHIF/Viewers
   - Demo: http://viewer.ohif.org/
2. Cornerstone Viewer (used in OHIF viewer)

   - GitHub: https://github.com/chafey/cornerstone
3. DICOM Web Viewer

   - GitHub: https://github.com/ivmartel/dwv